# In a transformer, how many times does the direction of magnetisation of the core reverse in one second?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

if we supply the primary coil of a transformer with 50Hz AC voltage, how many times will the direction of magnetisation of the core reverse each second?

This is what my book says:
Each time the current reverses direction, the direction of magnetisation of the core is also reversed, over and over again, usually 50 times a second. At each direction reversal, some energy is lost (overcoming the residual magnetic field still directed opposite to the new direction).

This is in the context of discussing hysteresis losses in a transformer.

I'm confused, because if we use 50Hz AC voltage, shouldn't the direction of the current change 100 times each second? So the direction of magnetisation of the soft iron core changes 100 times each second, not 50 times like the book says?

Comment: Don't forget that one cycle comprises an excursion to the "plus" and and excursion to the "minus"

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. While frequency of the magnetization oscillation at any point of the core is 50Hz, number of reversals (= points of time where magnetization changes direction) per second is twice that - 100 reversals per second.

This is about confusion in words - "frequency" means number of complete cycles; while "number of reversals" seems to mean number of points where the magnetization vanishes. Since magnetization vanishes twice per cycle, this number is twice the frequency. So the book seem to be in error.